# Equivalent to Eclipse "Compare Editor" for Visual Studio (2010 Professional Edition)

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, plugins, diff

1. It's a diff/edit tool, typically used to view/edit differences between the working and base copy of a file (pre-commit), or two repository revisions (when doing a peer review)
2. It supports 'internal structures', e.g. Java file comparisons can show you the differences based on methods, fields, and classes. These structural comparisons aren't thrown off by the ordering of the file changing like a traditional 'diff' may be.
3. It supports editting as normal (e.g. with Intellisense, 'Go To Definition' and 'Find All References' options).

I already have feature [1] via SourceGear DiffMerge and AnkhSVN.

I crave features [2] and [3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.devart.com/codecompare

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), a commercial product with a 30-day trial.  I don't believe I've seen a product that does exactly what you want, though.